# Stack based Calculator in Python

Tags: python-3.x, calculator

I programmed a calculator with int operations. The calculator stores functions in a dictionary. Also, the calculator stores how many arguments the function takes in a dictionary.

The input format is arguments followed by module and function name. These are split by lines and spaces. Input lines that start with a # are comments and are ignored by the calculator.

In order to use a value from the previous functions, an argument can be skipped and will be inserted in the front of the functions arguments.

The code is in three modules: fn (stores the functions), int_ops (int arthmatic operations), and run.py (grabs user input and outputs answer).

```
import fn
from fn import key, plugin_function
from int_ops import divide, multiply, subtract, add

"""
Run Module 

__fn__:
key(module_name: str, fn_name: str) -> str 
plugin_function(module_name: str, fn_name: str, number_of_args: int, func) -> None:
main() -> None

"""


def main() -> None:
    fn.plugin_function(add, "Int", "add", 2)
    fn.plugin_function(subtract, "Int", "subtract", 2)
    fn.plugin_function(multiply, "Int", "multiply", 2)
    fn.plugin_function(divide, "Int", "divide", 2)

    lines = ["2 2 Int add", "1 Int add"]
    stack = []
    split = ""

    for line in lines:
        split = line.split(" ")
        if split[0] == "#":
            continue

        """
        ignore extra spaces and extra tabs in input 
        """
        for e in split:
            e = e.replace(" ", "")
            e = e.replace("\t", "")

        """
        module name and function name are not args passed to call 
        """
        num_current_args = len(split) - 2
        needed_num_of_args = fn.num_args[key(split[-2], split[-1])]

        """
        add args from the stack for args not stated in input 
        """
        for row in range(needed_num_of_args - num_current_args):
            split.insert(0, stack[row])
            del stack[row]

        function = fn.function[key(split[-2], split[-1])]
        output = str(function(split))
        stack.append(output)
        print(stack)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()




"""
Int Module

fn

divide(parts: [str]) -> int
multiply(parts: [str]) -> int
subtract(parts: [str]) -> int
add(parts: [str]) -> int
"""


def divide(parts: [str]) -> int:
    """
    :param parts: parts of divide_int cmd
    Output: 0 if divsor is 0, int division otherwise
    """
    a = int(parts[0])
    b = int(parts[0])
    if b == 0:
        return 0
    return a // b


def multiply(parts :[str]) -> int:
    """
    :param parts: parts of the multiply_int cmd, ends with this name
    Output: scalar multiplication of ints
    """
    a = int(parts[0])
    b = int(parts[1])
    return a * b


def subtract(parts:[str]) -> int:
    """
    :param parts: parts of the subract_int cmd
    Output: subtraction of two
    """
    a = int(parts[0])
    b = int(parts[1])
    return a - b


def add(parts :[str]) -> int:
    """
    :param parts: parts of the add_int cmd, ends with this name
    Output: sum as int of both number
    """
    a = int(parts[0])
    b = int(parts[1])
    return a + b
    
    """
Module containing the functions that can be run
This file has the mathmatical functions of the calculator

fn
key(module_name: str, fn_name: str) -> str
function(module_name: str, fn_name: str)
num_args(module_name: str, fn_name)
plugin_function(func, module_name: str, fn_name: str, number_of_args: int) -> None
"""


__fn__ = {}
__num_args__ = {}


def key(module_name: str, fn_name: str) -> str:
    """
    :param module_name: name of the module
    :param fn_name: name of the function
    Key used for this module
    """
    return module_name + " " + fn_name


def function(module_name: str, fn_name: str):
    """
    :param module_name: module the function is in
    :param fn_name: the name of the function
    Output: function
    """
    return __fn__[key(module_name, fn_name)]


def num_args(module_name: str, fn_name: str) -> int:
    """
    :param module_name: module of the function
    :param fn_name: name of the function
    Output: Number of parameters such as x and y (2) that the function takes
    """
    return __num_args__[key(module_name, fn_name)]


def plugin_function(func, module_name: str, fn_name: str, number_of_args: int) -> None:
    """
    :param module_name: name of the module
    :param fn_name: name of the function
    :param number_of_args: number of args the function takes (required to be str)
    :param func: the function to run
    Output: None
    """
    global __fn__
    global __num_args__
    __fn__[key(module_name, fn_name)] = func
    __num_args__[key(module_name, fn_name)] = number_of_args
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I missed a major announcement regarding very new versions of Python, this isn't a proper type hint:

```
def divide(parts: [str]) -> int:
```

To type-hint a list, you need one of:

```
from typing import List

def divide(parts: List[str]) -> int:  # Python 3.5+ 


def divide(parts: list[str]) -> int:  # Python 3.9+
```

---

You have another bug as well:

```
for e in split:
    e = e.replace(" ", "")
    e = e.replace("\t", "")
```

This will not change `split`. This puts the string returned by `replace` into `e`, then `e` is overwritten on the next iteration and the replaced data is lost. You'd need something like this instead:

```
replaced_split = [e.replace(" ", "").replace("\t", "")
                  for e in split]
```

Then, used `replaced_split` instead of `split`.

---

```
split.insert(0, stack[row])
```

You should really never insert into the front of a list, unless you have 0 performance requirements. When you insert into the front, it needs to shift every other element in the list to make room at the front (`O(n)`; where `n` is the size of the list). It's much better to add to the end using `append`, which is amortized `O(1)` iirc. If it's too messy adding to the end, switch to using a [`dequeue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) which allows for constant-time inserts at both ends.

---

Another bug:

```
a = int(parts[0])
b = int(parts[0])
```

`b` should be the element at index `1`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you overengineered this solution. Below is a barebones implementation in one file. The focus here is on keeping the runtime logic as simple as possible. That is, if you wanted a more robust system for adding operations, it should ideally still compile into a simple structure like a dictionary of operations before the calculator even begins.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Operation = namedtuple('Operation',['func','num_params'])

OPERATIONS = {
    'Int add': Operation(
        lambda a,b: int(a)+int(b),
        2
    )
}

def main() -> None:
    lines = ["2 2 Int add", "1 Int add"]
    stack = []
    for line in lines:
        tokens = [
            token.strip()
            for token in line.split()
        ]
        *args, dtype, operator = tokens
        operation = OPERATIONS[f'{dtype} {operator}']

        stack_args_needed = operation.num_params - len(args)
        for _ in range(stack_args_needed):
            args.append(stack.pop())

        result = operation.func(*args)
        stack.append(result)
        print(stack)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```